# Drop-right menu HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm creating a drop-right menu with CSS, but I don't know how to do it...

I have searched for some examples on internet, but the code of all of them are very extensive.

I have tried with this one, but as you can see, I get a terrible and ugly result....

How can I solve it?

There is a link with an example of the result that I expect: 
http://subefotos.com/ver/?fe969c98c2a25ac71c8c14d12a4c9a8co.png

Thanks!

```css
body {
    background-color: #CEF6F5;
    text-decoration: none;
}
aside {
    margin-top: 1%;
    height: 50%;
}
#content {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: red;
}
#menu {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
}
.menu {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Rancho', cursive;
}
.cl-menu {
    list-style: none outside none;
    display: inline-table;
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
}
.cl-menu li {
    padding: 5px 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
.cl-menu > li:hover {
    background-color: #303030;
    background-color: #66819C;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
.cl-menu li ul {
    display: none;
}
.cl-menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.8;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    font-weight: normal !important;
}
.cl-menu li ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc !important;
    border-top: none !important;
    border-left: none !important;
    border-right: none !important;
}
.cl-menu li ul li a {
    color: #green;
}
.cl-menu li ul li a:hover {
    color: #5j8548;
}
.cl-menu ul:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CEF6F5;
    font-family: 'Rancho', cursive;
}
```

```html
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rancho' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<html>

<body>

    <aside id='menu'>
        <ul class="cl-menu">

            <li> <a href="#">Mis pedidos</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Mi perfil</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Descuentos</a>
            </li>
            <li id='albumes'>Albumes
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Navidad 2015</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Navidad 2014</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Añadir al carrito</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Articulos seleccionados</a> </li>
            <li> <a href="#">Finalizar Pedido</a> </li>z
        </ul>
    </aside>

    <aside id="content">CONTINGUT WEB</aside>

</body>
    
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there was a lot of unnecessary code so i had cleaned it up and fixed it, here it is:

HTML:

```
<aside id='menu'>
    <ul class="cl-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Mis pedidos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Mi perfil</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Descuentos</a>
        </li>
        <li id='albumes'>
            <a href="#">Albumes</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Navidad 2015</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Navidad 2014</a>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Añadir al carrito</a>
        </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Articulos seleccionados</a>
        </li>
         <li>
            <a href="#">Finalizar Pedido</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
<aside id="content">CONTINGUT WEB</aside>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    background-color: #CEF6F5;
}

aside
{
    margin-top: 1%;
    height:50%;
}

ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li
{
    list-style:none;
}

a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#content
{
    float:right;
    width:80%;
    background-color:red;
}

#menu
{
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    background-color: #000;
}

.cl-menu li
{
    position: relative;
}

.cl-menu > li:hover
{
    font-weight:bold;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.cl-menu li:hover
{
    background-color:#66819C;
}

.cl-menu li a
{
    display: block;
    min-width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    color:#CEF6F5;
    font-family: 'Rancho', cursive;
}

.cl-menu li:hover a
{
    color:#FFF;

}

.cl-menu li ul
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display:none;
}

.cl-menu li:hover > ul
{
    display:block;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.cl-menu li ul li
{
    background: grey;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    border-top:none;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
}

.cl-menu li ul li:last-child
{
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/q6ouetwp/1/